# Googlemaps API - Greyscale

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code setup to apply a map for a variety of areas

```
var locations = [
  ['Liver Office - Liverpool Office', 53.40529, -2.988801, 1],
  ['Lond office - London Office', 51.515026, -0.086811, 2],

];
function plotMap(loc) {  

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng((locations[loc][1]), (locations[loc][2])),
    stylers: [
    { saturation: -100 } // <-- THIS
  ]
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),

  mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
     mapTypeControlOptions: {
     mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'tehgrayz']
    },
    icon: 'marketICO.png',
    title: (locations[loc][0])
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[loc][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, loc));
}

$('.livLink').click(function(){
    plotMap(0);
});
$('.lonLink').click(function(){
    plotMap(1);
});
    plotMap(0);
```

Has anyone managed to get their map greyscale - i've had a few attempts - including above - but no luck so far..

Comment: I suggest asking the second question as a second question.  You'll probably get better responses to each one that way.

Comment: point taken - i've opened a secondary question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345745/google-maps-map-reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not applying the styles correctly.

```
var styles = [{
    "stylers": [{
        "saturation": -100
    }]
}];

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    styles: styles,
    // your other options here
};
```

Or directly in the map options:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    styles: [{
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -100
        }]
    }],
    // your other options here
};
```

Check this nice tool: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html